# My free WordPress plugin's active installations is less than 10. But downloads is close to 1000 after several months. Why?

Tags: wordpress, installation, plugins, download, logbook

I made a free WordPress plugin for office visits logbook

https://wordpress.org/plugins/office-visits-logbook/

Active installations is less than 10. But downloads is close to 1000 after several months. Why? Any suggestions?

I waited for more than 10 months and the active installation is still less than 10. But downloads is close to 1000. It does not make sense.